# Long connection to active directory using python

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, ldap3

I'm using library ldap to connect to active directory.

```
import logging
import ldap

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

try:
    ldap_connect = ldap.initialize(host)
    ldap_connect.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    ldap_connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    logger.info('successful connection')
    ldap_connect.unbind()
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f'Error: {str(e)}')

try:
    ldap_connect.simple_bind_s(user, password)
    logger.info('successful bind LDAP')
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS as e:
    logger.warning('Error bind')
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f'Error: {str(e)}')
```

Connection initialization is fast and successful. The connection freezes at the authorization stage (simple_bind_s). Authorization takes about 15 minutes, but it should be up to a minute.
What could be the problem and why is it taking so long to log in to active directory?

I tryed abother library ldap3

```
import json
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM

class LDAPapi:
    def __init__(self, server: str, login: str, password :str , domain: str = "passport"):
        self.server = Server('server', get_info=ALL)
        self.conn = Connection(server, user=f'{domain}\\{login}', password=password, authentication=NTLM)
```

And got the same problem, it gets 10-15 minutes to connect on line Connection(server, user=f'{domain}\{login}', password=password, authentication=NTLM)

trace_level=2

````
((17, 3), {})
=> result:
None
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.set_option
((17, 3), {})
=> result:
None
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.set_option
((8, 0), {})
=> result:
None
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.simple_bind
((<login>, <password>, None, None), {})
=> result:
1
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.result4
((1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0), {})
=> result:
(97, [], 1, [])
<ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7>
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.unbind_ext
((None, None), {})
=> result:
None```
````

Comment: Have you tried raising the `trace_level` (https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.4.3/reference/ldap.html?highlight=trace_level#ldap.initialize) and checking what it says?

Comment: @gog I used trace_level=2 and got the next answer:
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.set_option
((17, 3), {})
=> result:
None
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.set_option
((17, 3), {})
=> result:
None
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.set_option
((8, 0), {})
=> result:
None
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.simple_bind
((<login>, <password>, None, None), {})
=> result:

Comment: @gog 
1
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.result4
((1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0), {})
=> result:
(97, [], 1, [])
<ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7>
*** <ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject object at 0x7> ldap://<host>- SimpleLDAPObject.unbind_ext
((None, None), {})
=> result:
None

Comment: Please add this stuff  to the question body, nobody can read it in the comments.

Comment: @gog added to question body